# [_TtGCs23_ContiguousArrayStorageC16SwiftDefaultApps11SWDATreeRow_ length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6180000ac9c0

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, unrecognized-selector

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

SWDATreeRow is a custom NSObject subclass defined as:

```
class SWDATreeRow:NSObject {
    var children: [SWDATreeRow] = []
    var count: Int { return children.count }
    var isLeaf: Bool { return children.count < 1}
    var rowTitle: String
    var rowContent: SWDAContentHandler?
    var roleMask: SourceListRoleTypes?
    var content: SWDAContentItem?

    init(_ name: String, content: SWDAContentHandler? = nil) {
        self.rowTitle = name
        if let content = content {
        self.rowContent = content
        self.roleMask = content.roleMask
        self.content = content.content as! SWDAContentItem
        }
        super.init()
    }
}
```

From what I've read, it would seem the exception is being caused by an object that does not have a "length" being asked for its length? I have no idea what that is, really, though.

The app DOES NOT CRASH when this happens, and I've managed to reproduce it reliably. The bug happens when hovering over a tree-row and tooltips would be shown.

Comment: Somewhere a `SWDATreeRow` object is passed where a string is expected. Maybe a Cocoa binding issue.

Comment: That was it, thank you! There was a stray tooltip binding, but not on the actual SWDATreeRow; it was in the TableColumn, that's why I couldn't find it.